# Generic Return Type of Linq Query and String.Join bad use

Tags: c#, linq, generics

EDIT 
Summary after solution had been given

*Linq query results are almost always presented with "*var*" implicit type or with typed *IENumerable< T>* like *IEnumerable< int>*. However simple more  generic *IEnumerable* is sufficient

*String.Join() does not have specialization for *IEnumerable* ( but has naturally one for *IEnumerable< T>* ) and fall back to *String.Join Method (String, Object[] ...)*. It then assumes that the linq query result *res* is an array of Object of size 1. I do not know why there is no overload for IEnumerable!

/EDIT

I had imagine that it would be possible to write generic linq query return types.
A first idea was to write a code like this:

```C#
class exLinq
{
    Func<IEnumerable>[] fun_list = new Func<IEnumerable>[]
    { () => {   int[]   data    =       { 1, 2, 5, 8, 11 };
                var     result  =       from d in data
                                        where 0 == d % 2
                                        select d;
                return result;
            }
      //() => Other queries that could be on string, double... collections
     };



    static void Main(string args[])
    {         
        foreach (var fun in fun_list)
        {
            var f = fun;
            var res = f();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",res));
        }
    }
}
```

However I got the result

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[System.Int32]

My linq query return type would be more adequat with *IEnumerable < int >* ( It works when I do this ) but I was wondering if I could mix in the same array/list queries that would have handle *strings*,*double* or whatsoever...

Up to now I got a correct code output with the modification

```C#
if ( res is IEnumerable<int>)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",res.Cast<int>()));
```

> 2, 8

More accustomed with C++, I had believed that I would be able to handle any "groups of object" with the "higher" class.

Any idea of how to correctly achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can do it if you convert each enumerable to an `object[]` before calling `string.Join`:

```
foreach (var fun in fun_list)
{
    var f = fun;
    var res = f();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",res.Cast<object>().ToArray()));
}
```

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is that

```
string.Join(", ", res);
```

calls [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350.aspx) of `string.Join`. The `params` modifier on the last array parameter allows it to be called with any number of parameters e.g.

```
string.Join(", ", 1, 2, 3);
```

Each of these parameters get added to an `object[]` which is passed to the method. The `Join` method calls `ToString` on each element in the array to format it in the output string.

This means that when you call

```
string.Join(", ", res);
```

the `ToString` method of the generated `IEnumerable` is called, which is where "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[System.Int32]" comes from. You can overcome this behaviour by creating the `object[]` yourself and passing it to `string.Join`.

You can also use

```
string.Join(", ", res.Cast<object>());
```

this resolves to a [different overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) of `string.Join` which calls `ToString` on each element of the input sequence.

Comment: +1 for preventing me to write a test for each type I would have need. Would you have any links that could explain why it works ? There are plenty resources on linq queries but they explain often the same basic mechanisms.

Comment: I tested it without the ToArray() function.
*Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", res.Cast<object>()));* works as well

Comment: May I ask you if you know a reason why there is no overload specialization of String.Join() for  _IEnumerable_? Do you know other cases like this one ?